# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'client'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

im trying to access a cached_property from a model and its returning
`'tuple' object has no attribute 'client'`

this is the model that has the cached_property

```html
class Creds(models.Model):
    tenant = models.OneToOneField('tenant.Tenant', unique=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


    @cached_property
    def client(self):
        from pos.api_client import APIClient
        return APIClient(self)
```

and here is where im trying to access the cached_property. and getting the error.

```html
class createCred(APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        tenant = get_object_or_404(Tenant, pk=request['tenant_id'])
        square_credential = SquareCredential.objects.get_or_create(tenant=tenant)
        client = square_credential.client
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the docs for [`get_or_create`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create).

> Returns a tuple of (object, created), where object is the retrieved or created object and created is a boolean specifying whether a new object was created.

So you would need something like:

```
square_credential, created = SquareCredential.objects.get_or_create(tenant=tenant)
client = square_credential.client
```

If you don't care if it was created you can use an underscore as a "throwaway variable" convention:

```
square_credential, _ = SquareCredential.objects.get_or_create(tenant=tenant)
```